# Find all function with the given properties

Tags: functions

How to find the functions $f$ with the following properties

$f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow [0,1]$

$x > y  \implies f(x) > f(y)$

$0 \le f(x) < 1$

$x > y \implies x(1-f(x)) > y(1-f(y))$

Comment: Hi. Can you show a bit of your work on this so far? This way it is easier to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

From $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow [0,1]$ and $0 \le f(x) < 1$ we can conclude that $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow[0,1)$.
From $x > y  \implies f(x) > f(y)$ we see that $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

Now we need to focus at $x > y \implies x(1-f(x)) > y(1-f(y))$.

Since $x > y$, we have that $$\frac{x}{y}>1...(1)$$

From $x > y  \implies f(x) > f(y)$ we have $1-f(x)<1-f(y)$ or $$\frac{1-f(y)}{1-f(x)}>1...(2)$$

And from $x(1-f(x)) > y(1-f(y))$ we get $$\frac{x}{y}>\frac{1-f(y)}{1-f(x)}...(3).$$

The system formed by (1), (2) and (3) is equivalent to $$\frac{x}{y}>\frac{1-f(y)}{1-f(x)}>1.$$

So you need to find such monotonically increasing functions that hold given inequality, and the range of which is [0,1).